# Load more activity cell CollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to create a activityCell, so when the user reach the button it will show an cell with an activity indicator. This seem to work fine however if `moreDataAvailable` is `false` it should remove this cell. However i keep getting following error?

`'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 0 from section 1 which only contains 0 items before the update'`

**numberOfItemsInSection**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    if section == 0 {
        return organizationArray.count
    } else {
        if self.moreDataAvailable == true {
            return 1
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

}
```

**Hide Collection Cell**

```
func hideCollectionViewFooter() {



    self.collectionView!.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 1)])
}
```

**numberOfSectionsInCollectionView**

```
override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 2
}
```

**cellForItemAtIndexPath**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("OrganizationCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! OrganizationCollectionViewCell


        cell.customerLabel?.text = organizationArray[indexPath.item].name.uppercaseString

        cache.fetch(key: organizationArray[indexPath.item].coverPhoto).onSuccess { data in
            cell.customerImageView?.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ActivityCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell
        return cell

    }


}
```

**Load More when reach bottom**

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if !loadingData && indexPath.item == organizationArray.count - 1 && self.moreDataAvailable {

            self.loadingData = true

            proposeAccess(false, success: {
                self.loadingData = false
            })

        }
}
```

**Update Organization and check if more data is available**

```
func updateOrganizations(refresh: Bool) {
    let realm = try! Realm()


    GetOrganization.request(String(self.lastLoadedPage), limit: String(limit), location: self.lastLocation!, radius: String(100), refresh: refresh,
    success: { numberOfResults in


        //Sort by distance


        self.organizationArray = GetOrganization.sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(realm.objects(Organization), location: self.lastLocation!)

       self.lastLoadedPage = self.lastLoadedPage + 1

        if numberOfResults < self.limit {
            //Hide FooterView
            self.moreDataAvailable = false
            self.hideCollectionViewFooter()

        }


    }, error: {
        self.organizationArray = GetOrganization.sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation(realm.objects(Organization), location: self.lastLocation!)

       print("error")
    })


}
```

Comment: where's your number of sections defined? Seems you're not adding the activityCell as a last item in section 0 but as a new item in a new section.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, i've added that and the hide cell metod

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you're trying to delete cell that not existed in current table view state. Probably moreDataAvailable already was false before request in updateOrganizations was finished.

I would recommend you using table footer view for displaying activity indicator. Also, after data is loaded you can display a number of loaded items.

Comment: Cant see where it goes wrong in my code: `updateOrganizations`is called in viewDidLoad and `reloadData` is in didSet in `organizationArray`. How can i use a tableViewFooter in collection view?

Comment: @PeterPik sorry, didn't notice it is collection view. E.g. `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`. Did you set `moreDataAvailable = true` before calling `updateOrganizations`?

Comment: Yes it is set to true

Comment: maybe i could use `viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`, but dont know whether it is possible to hide/remove this dynamically like you can with a cell

Comment: @PeterPik so check you're not calling reloadData on collectionView before deleting cell, or not calling hideCollectionViewFooter twice

Comment: i probably am since i have this `var organizationArray = [Organization]() {
        didSet {
            self.collectionView!.reloadData()
        }
    }`

Comment: so it worked when i moved the `if numberOfResults` code above the `sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation`, however this is not ideal since it should first hide the cell when the `sortOrganizationsByDistanceFromLocation` is done